# Extensions - where to start

Tags: module, extension, query

So, been using EE for some time but now want to push the limits and write some extensions and or plugin.

The extension needs to write the entry_id of the entry just published by any user OR the entry_id of the entry if posting a comment - to every members profile (or separate table).

When a member visits the entry, it would remove the entry_id from their list.

EG:

--Install "extension"

----Extension creates new table - exp_member_read_unread (User ID, list of entry_ids)

--User creates a new post or comments on entry

----On save, extension kicks in and records the entries entry_id to each members exp_members_read_unread column. (eg: entry_id column = 1,2,4,99,6)

**Background**: I'll be creating a server side read/unread visited/not visited since new stuff added - list for each member.

Second to this, I will need another plugin/extension to modify the users read/unread list once visited. That'll be another post I expect.

I can pound away at creating an SQL query but no solid idea on where to start or if an extension is the right approach. The docs are somehwat overwhelming to a N00b and cannot find simple starter examples - so looking to tap the brightest minds where possible :)

Comment: Did you get the answer you where looking for if so check it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i didn't read all the functionality you are wanting to create. To create all of the things you are wanting to do you will need to create a "module" there isn't a tone of great documentation out there on how to do that but here is a great read and information about the different types of EE extensions and small tutorials on doing so... I hope this helps and answers your questions.

http://ee-recipes.com/articles/page/the_different_types_of_expressionengine_add_ons

At the bottom you can click on each one giving you more info on each.

Here is a link to a easy module tutorial from the same source:

http://ee-recipes.com/articles/details/our-first-module-part-1

http://ee-recipes.com/articles/details/our-first-module-part-2-setting-up-the-file-structure

http://ee-recipes.com/articles/details/our-first-module-part-3-creating-a-database-table

The rest of the series is on the right hand side.

Comment: This is a pretty decent tutorial as wel: http://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/how-to-develop-expressionengine-add-on/ Gives you a solid base to start from, slides and video are great